# How to control UITableViewCell's label appearance via UIAppearance?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiappearance

I'm using a `UITableView` from an external library. This table view creates `UITableViewCell`s using `style: .default`. I want to change the appearance of the cell, most importantly the cell's label text color, without resorting to changes to that library.

I've tried the following, unsuccessfully:

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().textLabel?.textColor = .systemBlue
UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = .systemPink
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.self]).textColor = .systemTeal
```

Text color remains black. (I'm aware that cells use the internal `UITableViewCellLabel` class, and haven't found a way to access its appearance proxy)

Interestingly, `UILabel.appearance().textColor = .systemGreen` *does* affect the appearance of table section headers in a grouped table, but only for those sections that initially appear on-screen. Scrolling the table so that new sections appear shows their headers with black text labels, and through reuse, scrolling back to the original sections redisplays these headers with black text as well.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Table views, cells, headers, footers, etc can be quirky. UIKit does a lot of behind-the-scenes work, particularly with the default properties.

You have a couple options:

You can set the label's text color in either `cellForRowAt` or `willDisplay cell`, or...

Create a custom table view cell. You can then use the appearance proxy:

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyBasicCell.self]).textColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: Thanks, that's precisely what I want to avoid. As I said, the code isn't mine, but buried deep inside an Objective-C cocoapods library that I'm not particularly keen on forking...